# QMediaPlayer and volume control in decibel

Tags: volume, decibel, qtmultimedia

I’m rewriting my music player from Qt4 to Qt5. I switched from Phonon to QtMultimedia. I now have a serious problem with volume control. To support ReplayGain, I read the tags from media files and then change the volume with every track to keep it equal.

In phonon I use setVolumeDecibel because the volume differences stored in tags are in dB. But in QtMultiMedia I can not use it. The QMediaPlayer class only has a setVolume function. Is there any other possibility how I could control the volume in dB? What is the calculation for setVolume internally? Maybe I could reverse it to set the volume in dB.

Or do you have any other advice what I should do?